# Finishing the final step of the Tietze extension theorem

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This is the proof of the Tietze extension theorem where $X$ is a normal space:

Lemma. Let $X$ be a normal space, $A \subseteq X$ be a closed subspace, and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for some $C>0$ we have $|f(x)| \leq C$ for all $x \in A$. There exists a continuous function $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(x)| \leq \frac{1}{3} C$ for all $x \in X$ and $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \frac{2}{3} C$ for all $x \in A$.

Tietze Extension Theorem

Without loss of generality we can assume that $[a, b]=[0,1]$. For $n=1,2, \ldots$ we will construct continuous functions $g_{n}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
(i) $\left|g_{n}(x)\right| \leq \frac{1}{3} \cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}$ for all $x \in X$;
(ii) $\left|f(x)-\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_{i}(x)\right| \leq\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$ for all $x \in A$.
We argue by induction. Existence of $g_{1}$ follows directly from Lemma. Assume that for some $n \geq 1$ we already have functions $g_{1}, \ldots, g_{n}$ satisfying (i) and (ii). In Lemma take $f$ to be the function $f-\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_{i}$ and take $C=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$. Then we can take $g_{n+1}:=g$ where $g$ is the function given by the lemma.

Let $\bar f_{n}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_{n}$ and let $\bar f:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g_{n}$. Using condition (i) we obtain that the sequence $\left\{\bar f_{n}\right\}$ converges uniformly to $\bar{f}$ (exercise). Since each of the functions $\bar{f}_{n}$ is continuous, thus by Proposition $11.6$ we obtain that $\bar{f}$ is a continuous function. Also, using (ii) be obtain that $\bar{f}(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in A$

So my question is, it seems like there is a final step missing. Our extension actually maps $X \to [-1,1]$ but we want it to be a mapping to $[0,1]$ which is what the Tietze extension theorem should be. Is there a way to modify our extension so we get this?

Comment: Replace $\overline f$ with $\max\{\overline f,0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state the Tietze extension  theorem, but certainly you consider $f : A \to [a,b]$ and then w.l.o.g. $[a,b] = [0,1]$.

You are right, you get an extension $\bar f : X \to [-1,1]$ of $f$. But now simply take $\tilde f = \lvert \bar f \rvert : X \to [0,1]$. This is a continuous function and you have $\tilde f(a) =  \lvert \bar f(a) \rvert =  \lvert f(a) \rvert = f(a)$ for $a \in A$.